# Create Generic Repository InsertOrUpdate function (Error)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to create a InsertOrUpdate function on an abstract layer on my generic repository, to be inherited by my concrete object repository:

**This is my code:**

```
 public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
 {
    private readonly OhmioEntities context = new OhmioEntities();

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> Findpredicate)
    {   
        T _dbRecord = this.FindBy(Findpredicate).FirstOrDefault();
        if (_dbRecord != null)
        {
            // Edit the record
            _dbRecord = entity;
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        }
        else
        {
            // Agrego el registro
            context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(entity);
        }

        // Save Changes to DB
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
public class ClientsRepository : GenericRepository<Clients>
{
  Clients _cli = new Clients(){ClientID=1,ClienName="My New Client"};
  this.InsertOrUpdate(_cli, o => o.ClientID == 1);
}
```

The idea is that if ClientID=1 Existe, the records get edited. If not a new record is inserted. It works perfect on Insert new object, but it gives me error on this line:

```
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

That says:

> {"ObjectStateManager do not contain a ObjectStateEntry with reference to a object of type 'DataLayer.Clients'."}

Why am i getting this? any clues? thanks!

**UDATE**

Well i get it working it just took some more code:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> Findpredicate)
    {   
        T _dbRecord = this.FindBy(Findpredicate).FirstOrDefault();
        if (_dbRecord != null)
        {
            // Edit the object
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_dbRecord, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            context.Detach(_dbRecord);
            _dbRecord = entity;
            context.AttachTo(entity.ToString().Split('.')[2], _dbRecord);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_dbRecord, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);                                
        }
        else
        {
            // add the object
            context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(entity);
        }

        // Save Changes to DB
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This load and detach trick in your UPDATE is not necessary. You can just only ask the database if the entity already exists or not without loading it (using `Any()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`):

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> Findpredicate)
{   
    bool exists = this.FindBy(Findpredicate).Any();
    if (exists)
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(entity);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
    }
    else
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(entity);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Alternatively you can load the original entity from the database and update its properties with the modified detached entity (with `ApplyCurrentValues`). It has the benefit that only the properties that have really changed are sent with the UPDATE statement to the database (but at the cost that the original entity must be loaded) while setting the whole entity state to `Modified` will also send the unchanged properties with the UPDATE to the DB (but with the benefit that the orginal doesn't need to be loaded):

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> Findpredicate)
{   
    T _dbRecord = this.FindBy(Findpredicate).FirstOrDefault();
    if (_dbRecord != null)
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(entity);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note that both solutions only work to update scalar properties of an entity. It doesn't work with changed relationships and navigation properties. There is no simple *generic* solution for this more general Update scenario with arbitrary object graphs.

Comment: Thanks! great info! The only thing is not clear is the last paragraph. What do you mean when you say that i cannot update relationships and navigation? if my client has a PK field related to other table on EF, it will not change? thanks again!

Comment: @ericpap: For example: If your `Client` entity has a foreign key property `AddressID` to an `Address` entity and you change this `AddressID` from `2` to `3` then the update will work because `AddressID` is a scalar property. If you change the navigation property `Client.Address` it won't work. More difficult is the case when you have a collection, for instance `Client.Orders` and you remove orders from this collection, add new orders or change orders in that collection. This won't be updated to the DB with the simple methods above. Not to mention more complex things like grandchildren...

Comment: I tried your code and works flawless! i try something similar but it gives me error on the attach. Now i works perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new `Client` object, but I guess haven't added in the context yet. Try adding in context first then change its state to `Modified`.

Plus your `FindBy` function is being used just as a signal, maybe you can use `Any` function instead of actually loading the entity in this function and change the return type to `boolean`.

One more thing your example usage of your class is a bit weird. I am NOT sure whether we can directly call a method in a class like you are calling without having this method in some other method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the problem as you mention is that i need to attach the edited object. The problem is that if i attach the edited object i get an error of object already exist. Finally i found a solution, please see my update. On your second point, FindBy is not used only as signal: if the object exist i need a reference to that object. I don't understand point 3 can you be more specific?

Comment: @ericpap my last point was actually regarding your concrete class `ClientsRepository`, in this class you are calling `this.InsertOrUpdate` method directly without having this line in some method.